# How to convert results returned from bigquery to Json

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery

Currently using python to pull data from bigquery after getting the result need to convert it in JSON format.How to convert the results to JSON ?

```
    Query = """
with data AS (
SELECT
end_time,
total_bytes_processed,
query
FROM
`project-id.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`
WHERE  date(end_time) = '2021-07-28'
GROUP BY
end_time,
job_id,
total_bytes_processed,
query
ORDER BY total_bytes_processed DESC
)
select as value
array_agg(struct( end_time,
regexp_extract(query, r'(?i)\sfrom\s+`?(?:[\w-]+\.)*([\w-]+\.[\w-]+)`?\s' ) as table,
(total_bytes_processed/1099511627776) * 5 as cost, query) 
order by (total_bytes_processed/1099511627776) * 5  desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from data
group by timestamp_trunc(end_time, minute)
 """
```

I have found  this [To JSON STRING FUNCTION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string) but I have yet to figure how to implement it into this statement.  help or hints how to get desirable result from BigQuery will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do this using 2 with clauses as shown below

```
with data AS (
SELECT
end_time,
total_bytes_processed,
query
FROM
region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE  date(end_time) = '2021-07-28'
GROUP BY
end_time,
job_id,
total_bytes_processed,
query
ORDER BY total_bytes_processed DESC
),
DATA1 AS (
select as value
array_agg(struct( end_time,
regexp_extract(query, r'(?i)\sfrom\s+`?(?:[\w-]+\.)*([\w-]+\.[\w-]+)`?\s' ) as table,
(total_bytes_processed/1099511627776) * 5 as cost, query) 
order by (total_bytes_processed/1099511627776) * 5  desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from data as t
group by timestamp_trunc(end_time, minute)
)
select TO_JSON_STRING(t,true) as data
from DATA1 AS t
```

This is the result I get

[image]